# Converting Number IDS to information sql lite

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

"Write a single SQL statement to generate two rows of information: one row showing the number of tracks formatted in AAC media type, and the other row showing the number of tracks formatted in non-AAC media type. There should be two columns in the output: first column is named Media which has the value AAC or non-AAC; second column is named Tracks which shows the total number of tracks"

The ACC type files are listed as IDs from 1-5 vairing from ACC and non ACC mediatypes. eg. 1 = Protected ACC file
                2 = Unprotected ACC file
                3 = mp4 file 
etc.

Obviously the first two are ACC files and the 3rd is not. I was wondering How i can convert those numbers into two distinct rows "ACC" and "non-ACC" eg. 1 and 2 being ACC and 3 being non-acc!

All help will be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Obviously the first two are ACC files and the 3rd is not` ... nothing here is remotely obvious, because you didn't share any actual data with us.   Edit your question showing us input and desired output.

Comment: Homework? Hint: you can `GROUP BY` a `CASE`.